# Font weight css with local fonts

Tags: css

I am still working locally on a web project, and since I have the font 'Open Sans' installed I am trying to target the different weights, but none of the below css is working, how can I target the different font weights with local fonts? Thank you.

```
FONT-FAMILY: 'Open Sans Semibold';
font-weight: Semibold;
```

Comment: What do you mean by font installed locally ?

Comment: I mean that I am still working in fonts that I have installed on my computer.

Comment: For web projects the font should be included in the project, eg. `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` should be added to your html. Then set the font family